# Task List Predecessors

Tags: designer-workflow, scheduled-tasks

I have worked on MS Project and often used Predecessors to link my tasks and timelines. Tasks and Sub-tasks could be Auto-scheduled based on Predecessors.
I am trying to use the same in Sharepoint Task List.
For example-

```
Row 1 Task hast StartDate 04/01/2018 & EndDate as 04/03/2018
Row 2 Task hast StartDate 04/03/2018 & EndDate as 04/07/2018
```

By adding Predecessor to `Row2` Task, this will automatically auto-schedule with `Row1` and its `enddate` will be linked to `Row2` `StartDate`

I am unable to do this using SharePoint Task List.

Comment: This is something I have been also trying to figure out, since not everyone in our organization has a MS Projects license, but everyone uses regularly Tasks lists.
The fact that the predecessing tasks do not autoschedule is keeping the people away from using sharepoint and getting them to use Excel, and this keep us away from the MS 365 features that comes with wroking with sharepoint. Any expert has a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a year since this post.  But the only way I've found to do this is Open the Task List in MS/Project.(Tasks>List tab>Open in Project)   Update your predecessors there and synch back.  But that just seems to update the task with the new dates based on what you see in Project, not actually calculate within SharePoint.